# unable to ssh on the command prompt

Tags: ssh, prompt

I have a problem with ssh on my ubuntu laptop, but after several effort I was able to get the putty work by making changes to the proxy type: I check the http and set the proxyhost name to university.proxy and port to 8080.

The problem now is that I can not ssh on the command prompt for easy transfer of files. Can anybody help me out on this. I think the problem should be how to set the hostproxy and port in the sshd_config or ssh_config but I do not know how to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the admin of your University-proxy explicitly permits forwarding of non-HTTP traffic on that port you're plain out of luck; nothing you do on the client side will make this go away.